# How can I make this function more efficent, contains 3 loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this function which loops through a bunch of elements in a gantt chart that represent tasks. Each task has class of "link" and the attributes "id" and "pre".

"pre" represents the tasks predecessor.

The function is used to work out what each tasks predecessor is and then call another function which draws an arrow between them.

The only way I could figure how to do this was to first create an array of the tasks then loop through that array and get each tasks predecessor, loop through the array of tasks again and find the task thats id matches the predecessor and then call the draw function as below.

But this resulted in three loops with one loop inside another as below and I cant help thinking there would be a more efficient way of doing the same thing? My application is slow as it is, this will just make it worse.

Can anybody suggest a way of rewriting this function to be more efficient?

P.S the application is to big to do a jsfiddle for this and the code is fairly self explanatory.

```
 //Adds relationship link arrows between tasks
function add_arrows()
{
    var ttask = new Array();
    var pre = 0;

    //loop through all task elements with the class link and add them to an array
    $(".link").each(function(i) 
    {
        ttask[i] = $(this);
    });

    //loop through the array if tasks
    for (var i=0, l=ttask.length; i < l; i++ ) 
    {
        //if its not the first task get its predecessor value
        if(i != 0)
        {
            pre = ttask[i].attr('pre');
        }
        //loop through the array of tasks again and get the task with an id that matches the predecessor value
        for (var j=0, k=ttask.length; j < k; j++ ) 
        {
            if(ttask[j].attr('id') == pre)
            {
                var predecessor = ttask[j];
            }
        }
        //if its not the first task, draw a link between the predecessor and current task
        if(i != 0)
        {
            drawlink(predecessor, ttask[i], ttask[i].attr('link')); //function takes: predecessor, current task, link type
        }
    }
}
```

After a suggestion below this looks the most efficient so far? Unless somebody can say why another method is computationally better?

```
function add_arrows(){
   $(".link").each(function(i) {
      var $el = $(this);
      if(i) drawlink($('#' + $el.attr('pre')), $el, $el.attr('link'));
   });
 }
```

Comment: how about just using jquery to get the predecessor element by its id?

Comment: I could do a  console.log(ttask[i]); but it will show a lot of stuff.

Comment: As a started, you should never be looping through things looking for element IDs. IDs should be unique, and you can find the element using document.getElementById()

Comment: I understand that, I probably should have used a custom attribute task_id or something.

Answer (score 2):

Surely its just finding all the elements that have a predecessor (judging by your code, that have a `pre` attribute) and adding a link to the element that is indicated by their `link` attribute.

something like:

```
 $('[pre]').each(function(i,el){
        var self = $(el),
        link = self.attr('link'),
        predecessor = $('#' + link);
        if (predecessor.length)
        {
            //i.e. A predecessor has been found, assuming that #0 is not an element
            drawlink(predecessor, self , link );
         }
    });
```

Comment: all tasks have the pre attribute but the first task cant have a predecessor. getting error el.attr is not a function

Comment: When you say the first task can't have a predessor, but it has a pre attribute, is that pre attribute empty?. Also sorry, forgot to wrap up the el with $, code modified

Comment: Its not empty it contains 0.

Comment: hmm not doing anything, no errors but no links arrows either

Comment: Sorry, had an extra space in the string, try now

Comment: Still nothing. So far I am liking RobG's suggestion of function add_arrows(){
    var ttask = new Array();
    var pre = 0;
    $(".link").each(function(i) {
        var $el = $(this);
        if(i) drawlink($('#' + $el.attr('pre')), $el, $el.attr('link'));
    });
}

Comment: Well if that works for you .... you don't need the ttask array though eh, nor the pre = 0. I would say the issue with my code that you are having is clearly establishing the link !== '0' bit. Possibly doing a trim on it or a cast, or establishing if there is not an element on the page with a zero (0) for an id (I hope not), meaning that #0 would never return anything, so you wouldn't need the link !== '0' anyway as predecessor.length would be zero (0, false) but without knowing the HTML I can't really say

Comment: yeah thanks! Its amazing how much my code could be cut down lol. Guess I'm not quote a Jquery wizz yet!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function add_arrows(){
$(".link").each(function(i) {
    var predecessor = (typeof ($(this).attr('pre')) !== "undefined") ? $("#"+($(this).attr('pre'))) : null;
    drawlink(predecessor, $(this), $(this).attr('link'));
});
}
```

Comment: This almost works but its not correct because of the  if(i != 0) {} wrapping everything means that task one is missed out entirely. task one can be another tasks predecessor it just cant have any of its own.

Comment: @RobG That works! Not sure I fully understand it all? Can you make it a proper answer with comments

Answer (score 0):

It seems that elements with a class of "link" can have a "pre" attribute that specifies the element that they are a predecessor for. Presumably each element only has one predecessor. Each link element also has a link attribute.

The *drawlink* function takes three arguments: the predecessor, the element and its link attribute value.

Get a list of the elements with class link, then iterate over it and call *drawlink* for each element that has a not empty pre attribute.

```
function joinPredecessors() {
  $('.link').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var pre = el.attr('pre');

    // Only draw a line if the element has a predecessor
    if (pre != '' && pre != null) {
      drawlink($('#' + pre), el, el.attr('link'));
    }
  });
}
```

Given you asked for "efficient", the above is concise but likely slow, a plain javscript method is:

```
function joinPredecessors() {
  // Work with plain JS and DOM
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
  var el, pre;

  for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = links[i];
    pre = el.getAttribute('pre');

    if (pre != '' && pre != null) {
      // Pass jQuery objects
      drawlink($('#' + pre), $(el), el.getAttribute('link'));
    }
  }
}
```

which is hardly any more code and [about twice as fast](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-pojs-30023), at least in IE and mobile Safari.

Comment: I will try this out later, efficient is what I was after!

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me because the elements passed to drawlink doesn't contain the elements width or height properties. I get this error item.width(...) is null

Comment: It's passing jQuery objects to *drawlink*, which is what the OP does, so I don't know why you get that error.